# Extracting a script

Tags: ajax, jquery, find

I have a DIV I want to ajax-load.  The contains javascript that needs to run.  I ran across [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073951/scripts-running-in-jquery-ajax-loaded-pages-run-document-ready-too-early) that talks about loading the scripts after the main content has loaded.  However I cannot get it to work, primarily because I can't find the scripts in my content!

Consider the following:

```
$('<p />').html('<div>x</div>').find('div').html()
"x"
```

(for some reason the line below wouldn't work:

```
$('<p><div>x</div></p>').find('div').html()
null
```

However, there's something special about scripts:

```
$('<p />').html('<script>x=1</script>').find('script').html()
null
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: FYI, The reason this doesn't work: `$('<p><div>x</div></p>').find('div').html()` ...is that it isn't valid for a `<p>` element to have a `<div>` element as a descendant. The browser is kicking it out.

Comment: hmm... `$('<div><p>x</p></div>').find('p').html()` does work - however `$('<div><script>x=1</script></div>').find('script').html()` doesn't...

Comment: Yes, `$('<div><p>x</p></div>').find('p').html()` works because it *is valid* to have a `p` as a child of `div`. The reverse is not valid, which is why `$('<p><div>x</div></p>')...` doesn't work. The reason `$('<div><script>x=1</script></div>')` doesn't work is because... well see the answers below. ;o)

Comment: @patrick dw, the answers below don't really address the issue

Answer (score 0):

Script tags get scrapped from jQuery `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

Neal is right. I'd recommend adding the script tag with plain JS:

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
script.text = 'alert("testing");';
// if you're linking to a remote script, use script.src instead

document.getElementById('parentID').appendChild(script);
// to append to the body, use document.body.appendChild
```

Comment: I can't because I'm not building this myself.  I'll get a string from somewhere and it may have a script section in it